# Filtering two lists of objects with same props in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, object

I have two lists of objects:

**1 - list_one**

```
[{'name': 'Jhon', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '1'},
 {'name': 'Jhon', 'OS': 'Iphone', 'impact': '1'},
 {'name': 'Roger', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '1'},
 {'name': 'Clev', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '2'}]
```

**2 - list_two**

```
[{'name': 'Jhon', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '3'},
 {'name': 'Roger', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '3'}]
```

And I need to have just one list, removing the objects that have *name* and *OS* equal in both lists, then the **final list** will be like this:

```
[{'name': 'Jhon', 'OS': 'Iphone', 'impact': '1'},
 {'name': 'Clev', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '2'}]
```

Comment: I don't see any correlation between these lists assuming "number" is "impact"

Comment: by number you mean OS?

Comment: I don't see any logic on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check only 'name' and 'OS', so, first, make auxiliary lists containing items reduced to only these two keys. Next, for both lists, sort out those items that have their equivalents in the other list.

```
list1 = [{'name': 'Jhon', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '1'},
         {'name': 'Jhon', 'OS': 'Iphone', 'impact': '1'},
         {'name': 'Roger', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '1'},
         {'name': 'Clev', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '2'}]
list2 = [{'name': 'Jhon', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '3'},
         {'name': 'Roger', 'OS': 'Android', 'impact': '3'}]
list1_aux = [{'name': item['name'], 'OS': item['OS']} for item in list1]
list2_aux = [{'name': item['name'], 'OS': item['OS']} for item in list2]

res = [item for item in list1 if {'name': item['name'], 'OS': item['OS']} not in list2_aux]
res += [item for item in list2 if {'name': item['name'], 'OS': item['OS']} not in list1_aux]
res
```